# Gantt chart json/javascript

Tags: visualforce, charts

I'm trying to create a gantt chart in a visualforce page WITHOUT using an app. So far I have tried both 
http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/gantt-chart-in-salesforce-using-jquery-and-json/

and

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000097EkIAI AND

Both of these are not giving me any errors, but they only show a blank screen. My code is exactly the same as in their examples. What am I missing?

For example one--

```
/**
    Author - Jitendra Zaa
    This controller class is used by the VF page "GanttChartData" to generate the JSON
*/
public with sharing class GanttChartData {

    public String jsonString {get;set;}

    //Constructor
    public GanttChartData()
    {
        jsonString = prepareData();

    }
    //Temp Method to prepare the Data
    private String prepareData()
    {
        List<ReservationDetail> dtlObj = new List<ReservationDetail>();

        ReservationDetail obj1 = new ReservationDetail();
        ReservationDetail obj2 = new ReservationDetail();
        ReservationDetail obj3 = new ReservationDetail();

        obj1.setFromDate(String.valueOf(datetime.newInstanceGmt(2012,04, 17, 0, 0, 0).getTime()));
        obj1.setToDate(String.valueOf(datetime.newInstanceGmt(2012,04, 17, 05, 30, 0).getTime()));
        obj1.desc_PH = 'Booked by : Jitendra <br /> for JQuery Demo';
        obj1.label = 'Jitendra';
        obj1.customClass = 'ganttRed';

        obj2.setFromDate(String.valueOf(datetime.newInstanceGmt(2012,04, 17, 20, 30, 0).getTime()));
        obj2.setToDate(String.valueOf(datetime.newInstanceGmt(2012,04, 17, 23, 30, 2).getTime()));
        obj2.desc_PH = 'Booked by : Tuiya <br /> for Wireless Lecture';
        obj2.label = 'Tuiya';
        obj2.customClass = 'ganttOrange';

        obj3.setFromDate(String.valueOf(datetime.newInstanceGmt(2012,04, 19, 09, 30, 0).getTime()));
        obj3.setToDate(String.valueOf(datetime.newInstanceGmt(2012,04, 19, 16, 30, 2).getTime()));
        obj3.desc_PH = 'Booked by : Santosh <br /> for SAP Basis';
        obj3.label = 'Santosh';
        obj3.customClass = 'ganttGreen';

        dtlObj.add(obj1);
        dtlObj.add(obj2);
        dtlObj.add(obj3);

        Room r = new Room();
        r.name = 'Training Room';
        r.desc_PH = 'This is Training Room';
        r.values = dtlObj;

        List<Room> r1 = new List<Room>();
        r1.add(r);

        return JSON.serialize(r1);
    }
    public class RoomList
    {
        public List<Room> rooms;
    }
    public class Room
    {
        public String name{get;set;}
        //Below var name - desc
        public String desc_PH{get;set;}
        public List<ReservationDetail> values{get;set;}
    }

    public class ReservationDetail
    {
        //actual variable name needed was "from", but it is keyword so we cant use that
        public String frm_PH{get;set;}
        public String to{get;set;}

        public String desc_PH{get;set;}
        public String label{get;set;}

        /*
            Custom class Can be anything from below:
            ganttRed
            ganttGreen
            ganttOrange

        */
        public String customClass{get;set;}

        public void setToDate(String val)
        {
            to = setDate(val);
        }
        public void setFromDate(String val)
        {
            frm_PH = setDate(val);
        }
        //Date should be in special format as it is used in regular expression
        private String setDate(String val)
        {
            return '/Date('+val+')/';
        }
    }
}
```

VF1:

```
<apex:page controller="GanttChartData"  contentType="application/x-JavaScript; charset=utf-8" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false">
{!jsonString}
</apex:page>
```

VF2:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false">

<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.GanttChart, 'style.css')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.GanttChart, 'js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.GanttChart, 'js/jquery.fn.gantt.js')}"/>



<div class="gantt" />

<script type="text/javascript">

$gc = jQuery.noConflict();

function getHostName()
{
    var p = $gc(location).attr('href');
    pathArray = p.split( '/' );
    var protocol = pathArray[0];
    var host = pathArray[2];
    return protocol+'//'+host;
}

    var jsonDataURL = getHostName()+'/apex/GanttChartData?core.apexpages.devmode.url=0';

    $gc(function () {
        $gc(".gantt").gantt({source: jsonDataURL, navigate: 'scroll', scale: 'hours', maxScale: 'hours', minScale: 'hours', hollydays: ["/Date(1293836400000)/"]});
     });

</script>

</apex:page>
```

For example two, same Apex, new VF page--

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false">

    <style>
        body {font-size:12px; background: #F3F3EC; padding-top: 0px;}
        .{font-family:arial;font-size:12px}
        h1 {cursor:hand;font-size:16px;margin-left:10px;line-height:10px}
        xmp {color:green;font-size:12px;margin:0px;font-family:courier;background-color:#e6e6fa;padding:2px}
        .hdr{
            background-color:lightgrey;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            padding-left:10px;
        }
    </style>


    <head>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Timeline, 'codebase/dhtmlxgantt.css')}"/>

    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Timeline, 'codebase/dhtmlxcommon.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Timeline, 'codebase/dhtmlxgantt.js')}"/>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        function createChartControl(htmlDiv1)
        {
            //project 1
            var project1 = new GanttProjectInfo(1, "Institutional Sales", new Date(2010, 5, 11));

            var parentTask1 = new GanttTaskInfo(1, "IS Planning Timeline", new Date(2010, 5, 11), 208, 100, "");
            parentTask1.addChildTask(new GanttTaskInfo(2, "Plan Development", new Date(2010, 5, 11), 100, 100, ""));
            parentTask1.addChildTask(new GanttTaskInfo(3, "Finalize Your Plan", new Date(2010, 5, 21), 24, 100, ""));
            parentTask1.addChildTask(new GanttTaskInfo(4, "Manager Discussions", new Date(2010, 5, 24), 80, 100, ""));
            parentTask1.addChildTask(new GanttTaskInfo(4, "Final Revisions", new Date(2010, 6, 4), 24, 100, ""));

            project1.addTask(parentTask1);


            var ganttChartControl = new GanttChart();
            ganttChartControl.setImagePath("{!URLFOR($Resource.Timeline, 'codebase/imgs/')}");

            ganttChartControl.setEditable(false);

            ganttChartControl.addProject(project1);

            ganttChartControl.showTooltip(false);
            ganttChartControl.create(htmlDiv1);
        }


    </script>


    </head>

    <body onload="createChartControl('GanttDiv')">
        <div style="width:100%;height:240px;position:absolute;" id="GanttDiv"></div>
    </body>



</apex:page>
```

Comment: I realize you stated that you're getting a white screen, but that's awfully non-specific. Could you check your JavaScript Console (F12 on most browsers) and see if you're getting any errors? That would help us out tremendously.

Comment: I don't know why I assumed this was apex/vf problem rather than a problem with the js. After checking the console, I do in fact see an error:

`TypeError: dateStr is undefined`

I'll add the js above

Comment: The js is too long to post, but here's a link:
http://pastebin.com/uMYJx8Lj

Comment: The problem *is* your Apex Code, after all. I think something got lost in translation. Give me a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gantt Chart code is expecting some variable names that are reserved keywords in Apex Code; they can't be used as variable or class or variable names (e.g. FROM, DESC). Usually, when I'm constructing JSON, I choose to use a `Map<String, Object>`, which works for serialization all of the time, regardless of reserved names/etc.

Here's a cleaned up, optimized version of how this library is expecting the data to be rendered:

```
/**
    Author - Jitendra Zaa
    This controller class is used by the VF page "GanttChartData" to generate the JSON
*/
public with sharing class GanttChartData {
    public String jsonString {get;set;}

    //Constructor
    public GanttChartData()
    {
        jsonString = JSON.serialize(
            new Map<String, Object>
            {
                'name' => 'Training Room',
                'desc' => 'This is Training Room',
                'values' => new List<Map<String, Object>>
                    {
                        new Map<String, Object>
                        {
                            'from' => '/Date('+datetime.newInstanceGmt(2012,04, 17, 0, 0, 0).getTime()+')/',
                            'to' => '/Date('+datetime.newInstanceGmt(2012,04, 17, 05, 30, 0).getTime()+')/',
                            'desc' => 'Booked by : Jitendra <br /> for JQuery Demo',
                            'label' => 'Jitendra',
                            'customClass' => 'ganttRed'
                        },
                        new Map<String, Object>
                        {
                            'from' => '/Date('+datetime.newInstanceGmt(2012,04, 17, 20, 30, 0).getTime()+')/',
                            'to' => '/Date('+datetime.newInstanceGmt(2012,04, 17, 23, 30, 2).getTime()+')/',
                            'desc' => 'Booked by : Tuiya <br /> for Wireless Lecture',
                            'label' => 'Tuiya',
                            'customClass' => 'ganttOrange'
                        },
                        new Map<String, Object>
                        {
                            'from' => '/Date('+datetime.newInstanceGmt(2012,04, 19, 09, 30, 0).getTime()+')/',
                            'to' => '/Date('+datetime.newInstanceGmt(2012,04, 19, 16, 30, 2).getTime()+')/',
                            'desc' => 'Booked by : Santosh <br /> for SAP Basis',
                            'label' => 'Santosh',
                            'customClass' => 'ganttGreen'
                        }
                    }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this answer is correct, but your code doesn't compile

`Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'Map' at line 26 column 24`

Comment: You're right. There was still some extra code in there.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and mark this as the answer, because it successfully solved my earlier error, but I am still not seeing the chart. It looks like jquery is also causing some problems. 

Error 1:
`Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.`

Error 2:
`TypeError: a is undefined`

both of these errors are in 1.5.1.min version of jquery. I wonder if using a newer version of jquery will help?

Comment: Actually, the getPreventDefault() is deprecated doesn't cause it to fail. I need to fix `a is undefined`

Comment: Here's the full console error information for `a is undefined`/`object is undefined`(nonminified version of jquery error)
http://pastebin.com/ausdAd6r